# creating Kable in R Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable

how can I put the following model construction into a kable in R markdown.

```
>modelTT <- glm(formula
           ,family=gaussian(link = "identity"), data=dataL_TT)

>regr_tab_NM(modelTT)

                                      Estimate Pr(>|t|)
        (Intercept)                    -2.6077  < 0.001
        Days_diff_Eff_Subm_2           -0.0114  < 0.001
        TR_BS_BROKER_ID_360_2           0.0344  < 0.001
        TR_BS_BROKER_ID_360_M           0.8551  < 0.001
        RURALPOP_P_CWR_2               -0.0083  < 0.001
        RURALPOP_P_CWR_M               -0.7106  < 0.001
        TR_B_BROKER_ID_360              0.0241  < 0.001
        TR_SCW_BROKER_ID_360           -0.0005  < 0.001
        PIP_Flag                        3.5838  < 0.001
        TR_BS_BROKER_INDIVIDUAL_720_2   0.0357  < 0.001
        TR_BS_BROKER_INDIVIDUAL_720_M  -0.0780  < 0.001
        Resolved_Conflictless5m         1.1547  < 0.001
        Resolved_Conflict5mTo1d         1.5352  < 0.001
        Resolved_Conflictafter1d        2.1279  < 0.001
        Priority_2Other                -1.1499  < 0.001
```

So first I started with 
  library(knitr) then kable(modelTT, .....) I'm not sure if this is correct.

Comment: I would recommend the use of the `stargazer` package. It saves a lot of trouble

Comment: I have installed stargazer. And I use the code stargazer(modelTT) and I can't see where the output is.

Comment: Does this link help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45724432/stargazer-output-is-code-not-a-table

Answer (score 1):

One can print tabular content from R functions directly in R Markdown with `kable()` by saving the object to be printed, and then using an inline R function (vs. a block) to render the table.

To print the regression coefficients from a model, one needs to identify the specific object that contains the coefficients and print it, rather than the entire `summary()` object. We'll illustrate with a simple example using `lm()`.

The output object from `summary(lm(...))` is a list of 11 objects, one of which is called `coefficients`. The `coefficients` object contains the regression slopes, standard errors, t and probability values.

The following code can be saved as an Rmd file and knit with `knitr` to print these items as a `kable()` table.

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

Stackoverflow question [48804938](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48804938/creating-kable-in-r-markdown) asked how to take output from a linear model and render it with kable in R Markdown. We'll run a `lm()` with the `mtcars` data frame and print the coefficients table with kable. 

```{r regression, echo = TRUE, warning = FALSE, eval = TRUE}
 library(knitr)
 fit <- lm(mpg ~ am + disp + wt, data = mtcars)
 theStats <- summary(fit)


```

At this point we can print the coefficients table with `theStats$coefficients` as the argument to the `kable()` function.

`r kable(theStats$coefficients)`
````

When we knit the document to HTML, it produces the following document.

[image]